# I want to delete multiple lines of file's output .which file is redirected

Tags: c#

I want to delete multiple string lines of files output.which file is redirected.
My code is as follows.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd ";
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C ipconfig";
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.Start();
    string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    p.WaitForExit();
    Console.WriteLine(output);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

OUTPUT  : I give correct answer.but i want only ip address of m/c. Other lines are deleted.
please give the answer of question with changes of code.

Comment: maybe add what you actually want to see from the output of ipconfig

Comment: @mellamokb It is more a sort of demand... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to run ipconfig? The [`NetworkInterface`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.aspx) class should be able to provide you the information you are looking for without requiring you to run an external process and parse text.

Comment: PLEASE give the changes of my code with the NetworkInterface class.

Comment: PLEASE give the changes of my code with the NetworkInterface class

Comment: @megha: The page I linked to has an example of how to print out all the information provided by the class. There is also a comment that points to [IPInterfaceProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipinterfaceproperties.aspx) with another example of how to print out the information about an IP address.

Answer (score 0):

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd ";
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C net view";
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.Start();
    string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    p.WaitForExit();
    Console.WriteLine(output);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

OUTPUT : 
server name                                   remark

---

//st1
//st2
//satishlap
//st6
//st10
command is completed successfully.

---

I give correct output.I want to only server name(//st1,//st2,//satishlap,//st6,//st10).
other infoemation is deleted. please the answer of my question with the changes of code.

Comment: If you are going to add more information, edit your question instead of posting something as an answer.

Comment: In my code, i want to only m/c connected to my m/c other information is deleted.plz give the hint.with changes of code. Thank you.